# How to remove Region and add new ContentControls from Module

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, region, prism-2

I've set only one region in Shell "LoginRegion"

```
<!-- Login Region -->
<Border Grid.Row="0">
    <ContentControl x:Name="LoginRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="LoginRegion"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>
```

And after login succeeded, I need to remove "LoginRegion" and add 3 other regions with new `LayoutRoot` grid definitions to Shell from code behind in Login module.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="93"/>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- Top Region -->
<Border Grid.Row="0">
    <ContentControl x:Name="TopRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="TopRegion"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>

<!-- Main Region -->
<Border Grid.Row="1">
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"
                    Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>

<!-- Bottom Region -->
<Border Grid.Row="2">
    <ContentControl x:Name="BottomRegion" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="BottomRegion"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this from Ron Gramann:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PrismLayoutManager.aspx

Layout Manager for Prism v2

it works for me